# .NET WCF - There is already a listener on IP endpoint when service auto restarts

Tags: wcf, windows-services

I have a WCF service that is deployed as a Windows service on a server.  It is configured to restart automatically on recovery (in the Properties dialog for the service in the Services.msc utility).  However, when the service auto restarts, it throws the following exception:

> System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException: There is already a listener on IP endpoint 0.0.0.0:8093.  Make sure that you are not trying to use this endpoint multiple times in your application and that there are no other applications listening on this endpoint.

It still starts, but in a faulted state.  When I manually restart it, I don't get this error (though it gives a warning when I attempt to stop the service after it has restarted in a faulted state).

It's as if the service is restarting too quickly and the Services manager thinks that there is still another service listening on that port.  I configured the service to restart after 5 minutes.  I also executed **netstat -a -n -o** at the command line to verify that the only service on that port is mine.

The proxy attempts to abort the service as follows:

```
public byte[] ConvertDocument(ConversionType conversionType, byte[] documentData)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        IDocumentConverter server = this.channelFactory.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            ((ICommunicationObject)server).Open();
            result = server.ConvertDocument(conversionType, documentData);
            ((ICommunicationObject)server).Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (((ICommunicationObject)server).State != CommunicationState.Closed)
                ((ICommunicationObject)server).Abort();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Has anyone else had this kind of issue?

**UPDATE:**

I am still having this issue, even after changing the InstanceContextMode to PerSession and Single.

I'm wondering if the client is keeping the connection alive on the port, so when the service restarts it thinks the port is already in use.

Could the way my client is implemented be responsible for causing the AddressAlreadyInUseException?  Such as swallowing the CommunicationException in the OperationContract, or creating and opening the channel on each call to the OperationContract.

Comment: It sounds like you might have a background thread hanging around that doesn't shut down in a timely manner when the service is stopped. See if you can nudge all your threads to shut down when you get the service shutdown notification.

Comment: Could having the InstanceContextMode set to PerCall cause issues with hanging threads?  Do I need to implement IErrorHandler or use an UnhandledException event handler to clean those up?

Comment: You should not have to in my experience - you don't have any threads of your own?

Comment: No, just those created by WCF.  This issue became apparent because of another issue.  A third party library we are using throws a System.AccessViolationException which tears down the whole service.  It is an unhandled exception.  Could that cause some weird issue with hanging threads in WCF?

Comment: Possibly. If you can run your service under a debugger and observe that it takes a while to shut down after getting the request from the service applet, try breaking into it in the IDE during this delay and see what threads are running and where their IPs are at.

Comment: Well, for now, I changed the InstanceContextMode to PerSession, and the service isn't being brought down.  That doesn't address the problem I posted about here, and I'm hoping I will still get to the bottom of it.